# Firebase android facebook,google,email login interface does not popup

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I've watched a tutorial on YouTube about how to integrate Firebase to android applications. Registered Firebase, add my facebook and app info, and add the necessary changes to my app but somehow my main interface which should show login screens does not show up. There is no build errors.

Here are my codes;

My build.gradle inside my app:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.bogroup.ucuncuprogram"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.4.0'
    //compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.4.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.0'
    //compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:25.2.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

My main java code:

```
package com.bogroup.ucuncuprogram;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import com.firebase.ui.auth.AuthUI;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 0;

    EditText et;
    private FirebaseAuth auth;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        if(auth.getCurrentUser() != null){
            //USER ALREADY SIGNED IN
            Log.d("AUTH", auth.getCurrentUser().getEmail());
        }else{
            startActivityForResult(AuthUI.getInstance()
                    .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                    .setProviders(AuthUI.FACEBOOK_PROVIDER,
                            AuthUI.EMAIL_PROVIDER,
                            AuthUI.GOOGLE_PROVIDER)
                    .build(),RC_SIGN_IN);
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode==RC_SIGN_IN){
            if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
                //user logged in
                Log.d("AUTH", auth.getCurrentUser().getEmail());
            }else{
                // user not authenticated
                Log.d("AUTH", "NOT AUTHENTİCATED");
            }
        }
    }
    public void tikla(View v){
        if (v.getId()==R.id.button){
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ikinciekren.class);
            CharSequence charlarim = et.getText();
            intent.putExtra("anahtar",charlarim);
            startActivity(intent);
            //
        }
        /*
        else if (v.getId()==R.id.button){
            //
        }
        */
    }

}
```

My main build.gradle file (not under app)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

My android.manifest.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.bogroup.ucuncuprogram">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ikinciekren">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.IKINCIEKREN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Also added google-services.json file under app and facebook id under in string.xml file

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing **`startActivityForResult()`** to:

```
startActivityForResult(
            AuthUI.getInstance()
                    .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                    .setProviders(Arrays.asList(
                            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.FACEBOOK_PROVIDER).build(),
                            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.EMAIL_PROVIDER).build(),
                            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.GOOGLE_PROVIDER).build()
                    ))
                    .build(),
            RC_SIGN_IN);
```

To learn more about authentication on Firebase UI library look at:
https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/auth

Comment: i heard my code is deprecated as you mentioned but when i try to change that part it says "Cannot resolve symbol 'IdpConfig'" what should i do to fix this?

Comment: Thanks, after adding configuration settings given in the link you gave it worked.